# Inner join of 2 tables is not working using yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to perform a query with join in Yii. Query is like that "select j.title,j.company_name from job_application a inner join jobs j on a.job_id = j.id"

My query in controller-sitecontroller

```
         public function actionmyjob()
         {
         $row = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('j.title,j.company_name')
        ->from('job_application a')
        ->join('jobs j','a.job_id = j.id')
        ->queryRow();
    echo $count=count($row);
       $this->render('myjob',array('row' =>$row));
      }
```

My view page myjob.php

```
 <?php
 foreach($row as $rows)  
 {
 echo $row->title."</br>";
 }

 ?>
```

Is there anything you can help? Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this $sql = ''; $fieldrecords =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryColumn();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no problem with your query. But still you should check using `CVarDumper::dump($row,10,true);`

And in your view file you should use this

```
<?php
 foreach($row as $rows)  
 {
 echo $rows."</br>"; // If you want to use only title then try $row['title']
 }
 ?>
```

---

And **if you are interested** in all the result then you should use **queryAll()**.

For this change your action to

```
public function actionmyjob()
         {
         $row = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('j.title,j.company_name')
        ->from('job_application a')
        ->join('jobs j','a.job_id = j.id')
        ->queryAll();
    echo $count=count($row);
       $this->render('myjob',array('row' =>$row));
      }
```

And your view to

```
<?php
 foreach($row as $rows)  
 {
 echo $rows['title']."</br>"; // change $row to $rows
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Now shows the errror Undefined index: title

C:\wamp\www\yii_new\jobsite_orginal\protected\modules\jobseeker\views\site\myjob.php(4).Line 4 is the    echo $row['title']."</br>";

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'php programmer' (length=14)
      'company_name' => string 'Impulse info solotion' (length=21)

Comment: you need to change $row to $rows as i have shown in my updated answer